# How does RSyslog receive log messages automatically?

Tags: syslog

*Relevant part:*

```
anisha@linux-trra~> sudo cat /var/log/messages
Aug 29 13:04:22 linux kernel: imklog 5.6.3, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Aug 29 13:04:22 linux rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.6.3" x-pid="1879" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Aug 29 13:04:22 linux kernel: [7.585951] type=1400 audit(1346225659.436:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/syslog-ng" pid=807 comm="apparmor_parser" Aug 29 13:04:22 linux kernel: [7.667712] type=1400 audit(1346225659.518:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/sbin/syslogd" pid=830 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

I couldn't find these PIDs on my system through `ps -el`.

- How do the programs *automatically* know that they have to send messages to RSyslog?
- Is it that all programs dump their messages at one place, and RSyslog picks up the relevant ones?
- Man page of Syslog says that Syslog reads its messages from a socket in /dev. **So, how does it correlate with the above two points?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all syslog daemons read incoming messages from:
`/dev/log`

Additionally syslog can bind to UDP socket on port 514.
See /etc/services::

```
$ cat /etc/services | grep syslog
syslog          514/udp
```

Second is mostly used for passing logs between syslog daemons. I.e. one logging server per cluster.

As a programmer you don't directly write to /dev/log but instead you call a posix function `syslog`::

```
#include <syslog.h>

void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
void closelog(void);
```

In fact all higher level languages give you an abstraction layer on top of these functions.